# Cross network interfaces using netplan on ubuntu server

Tags: server, wireless, ethernet, raspberrypi, netplan

I want configure into my raspberry pi 3 (using ubuntu server) a cross network using the Wifi and Ethernet.

Is this it's possible using netplan or we need back to use /etc/network/interfaces?

I have a gateway on wifi connection and i want set static ip address for ethernet and see the gateway of Wifi from my Ethernet connection and viceversa

```
                                                                             Computer 2
    WiFi Provider                                                         --------------
    -------------                    RASPBERRY PI3                       |              |
    |            |                   ___________                         |              |
    |            |        Wifi      |           |        Ethernet        |              |
    |            |   <----------->  |           |     <------------>     |              |
    |            |    192.168.43.1  |           |      192.168.110.1     |              |
    |            |    Gateway       |___________|         Gateway        ------------
    |____________|
                                                            -
          -                                                 |
          |                                                 |
          |                                                 |
          |                                                 |
    Computer connected 1------------------------------------|
                                                    Reach the other computer 2
```

Comment: I try to not jump to conclusions and just tell people they are wrong... but from reading, it looks like you could be doing some kind of unconventional lab setup in your home OR you could be misunderstanding a lot of terminology. Hard to decipher. Can you give more background? When I see 2 gateways i don't know which way to lean. When I see a term like "Wifi Provider", I lean a certain way. Whats the end goal? is it simply to have the 2 computers talk without a switch or a more ambitious setup? Normally I wouldn't question "why", I hate when people do that. But I cant understand the question

Comment: Sorry @WU-TANG if i don't explain in the best way my idea. I want use the raspberry with ubuntu server to comunicate 2 machines, one it's connected to wifi router (same for raspberry) and the other machine it's connected to ethernet port on raspberry but i want set a different ip and gateway for ethernet port. For example the Wifi give me 192.168.43.1 as gateway and i want reach this ip from computer connected by ethernet port (have other ip like 192.168.100.100)

Comment: I'm still not quite following the overall goal.. but either way, you are going to have to have a static route configured on each computer which points to the interface of its nearest connection on the raspberry pi... And then, I am not sure (it has been a while) if you can just pass traffic through a PC (rapsberry pi in this case) without some configuration... I believe you will have to enable forwarding... something along these lines... https://devconnected.com/how-to-configure-linux-as-a-static-router/

Comment: @WU-TANG i try that guide but i using ubuntu 20 for raspberry and use netplan and not the network interfaces (but maybe this is not a big problem it's just follow the steps). The first test i did it's set static ip address for ethernet interface to connect the laptop to raspberry and try to reach the raspberry but i can't because it's like a local loop (the computer says you are connected by ethernet) but never reach the raspberry